# Adding and Subtracting Time in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

## What I am trying to do

I am trying to return hours between start time and finish time. I am getting answers like .042 .057.

The reason for making sure the E4 cell is blank if there is no time is so my other cells formulas don’t return errors.

## Formula

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A4),ISBLANK(B4)),””,IF(B4=””,TO-A4+(TO<A4)*24,IF(B4<=”0″,B4-A4+(B4<A4)*24)))
```

## Cell values

A4 = Driver Time In

B4 = Manual over ride of a driver’s Time Out’

TO = A set time out of 4 pm

Comment: You should probably use the Excel date-time functions.

Comment: Cleaned up formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that if `A4` and `B4` are both empty the formula should return a blank, otherwise you get the difference between the two times as a decimal number of hours, e.g. `07:00` in `A4` and `15:15` in `B4` gives `8.25`. If `B4` is blank then end time is assumed to be `16:00`

Try this version:

`=IF(COUNT(A4,B4)=0,"",MOD(IF(B4="","16:00",B4)-A4,1)*24)`

format result cell as number

Comment: Sorry really new to all this